# What comes with Overwatch Origins Edition?

Tags: overwatch

I'm considering buying Overwatch Origins Edition for Xbox One. What is included in this edition?

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/overwatch-origins-edition/c1c4dzjpbc2v

Answer (score 4):

From the [wiki](http://overwatch.wikia.com/wiki/Origins_Edition)

> - 5 Origin Skins:
>
>   - Overgrown Bastion
>   - Security Chief Pharah
>   - Strike-Commander Morrison
>   - Blackwatch Reyes
>   - Slipstream Tracer
> - Player Portraits for Starcraft II:
>
>   - Tracer
>   - Reaper
>   - Pharah
>   - Winston
>   - Bastion
>   - Soldier: 76
> - Bonuses for other Blizzard games
>
>   - Tracer Hero for Heroes of the Storm
>   - Baby Winston Pet for World of Warcraft
>   - Overwatch Card Back for Hearthstone: Heroes of Warcraft
>   - Mercy's Wings for Diablo III

Comment: Will you get the other game bonuses on PC if you buy OW:OE  for XBox One? AFAIK, none of those are for console, so those rewards would go to waste otherwise.

Comment: @MageXy Diablo 3 is on console, at least.

Comment: @MageXy Yes; You do as long as you link the purchase to your battle.net account

Comment: The 'Origins Edition' has been renamed to the 'Game of the Year Edition'. The only difference is that the GotY edition also comes with 10 loot boxes.